# Access SaaS application with CNAME and SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, cname-record

We are running a SaaS application with nginx as webserver. Now we want to allow our customers to use their own domain for our application with setting up a CNAME alias.

I am currently testing with CNAME and first got an SSL error, cause the application is configured with a wildcard domain certificate for our own domain. But with CNAME the certificate shows the security error because of the other domain. So I created a certificate for the second domain and updated my nginx configuration to use that certificate for connections over the CNAME alias page.

But now I get a NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error, because the wrong certificate is sent back to the client.

If I open our subdomain of the application, I see the correct certificate is sent.

How can I check which server configuration nginx is using for the CNAME request?

Comment: did you solve your problem? I'm facing a similar situation rn